# Logging measurements from an analog Gas Meter

Tags: arduino, energy

I want to capture a gasmeter counter to log the gas consumption in my database.
Problem: till now I did not find a way to read the meter.
I tried a sensitive hall sensor that could react on the magnetic fiels of the counter without succes. There is no reflecting part on the counter that could be detected with a IR sensor.
Replacing the meter is too expensive.

So what are the options?
The meter makes some noise. There is a regular 'click' in it. Could it be possible to detect the noise with a little microphone and react on the click? How should I build a circuit for such issue?
Or is there a possibility to read the little stripes next to the number with one or another kind of sensor?
Or other options maybe?
[image]

Comment: What about a camera and image recognition?

Comment: Is there the possibility of pulling the meter apart to run out a couple of wires? I'm guessing for that mechanical readout the click is a solenoid actuation that should be easy enough to pick up and probably the easiest way unless there's some legal or other reason not to modify it.

Comment: No, I cannot open the meter, because it is the official one that is sealed.

Comment: Well an IP camera focused on the meter could be a good stand in until a proper solution is found.. have a picture taken every day might be all you need... Then you could run some OCR over the pictures if you wanted to save some people time.

Comment: when do you get click sound?(if you get click sound whenever the meter count increases)

Comment: A narrow-angle light sensor (EG IR proximity sensor) pointed at the number / graticule on the far right would give reasonable resolution, or the cheapest USB webcam + raspberry Pi + some basic image processing to detect the pixels going from black to white. If it's low enough bandwidth you could even do it with a smaller micro, but the Pi is so cheap it hardly seems worth it.

Comment: @JohnU how by using narrow angle sensor? rpi solution is okay

Comment: An optical/IR sensor that transmits a small beam of light & senses the reflected light, these are very common & cheap but usually need to be very close to the surface of the thing they are sensing. This may be impractical, so you either need to find one that can work in your application or maybe build something using an IR LED, IR detector, and some lens / light tube arrangement to focus the beam/sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Going off John U's comment above, you could consider a linear light sensor array, such as this:

http://parallax.com/product/28317

It has a lens, and is focusable.  It has 128x1 pixels, and can be read with an arduino.  Set it up to look at the graticule on the last digit, and use an arduino to observe the white/dark stripes as they move across the linescan sensor.  It's sensitive to infrared light, so you can light it at night without attracting unwanted attention.

Use the arduino to turn that into a value.

Another similar option would be to tear apart an optical mouse and use its sensor to watch the numbers move below it.  Might be too far to sense it without changing the lens, though.

Also, consider attaching a microphone or sensitive accelerometer to the bellows casing itself, near the part which switches each time a bellow fills.  You might be able to sense that "click" well enough to discern it from outside noise.

Comment: I want to try the idea with the microphone. I like to test it with Arduino Uno. Now I have to search for the best way to convert the 'click' in a 1 to a digital input on the arduino. Any idea how a circuit for that looks like? I'm a progammer, but not so good in developing a new circuit.

Comment: @WannesNaf For you, then, I'd suggest attaching the microphone to the analog input, reading the value 10 thousands times a second, and doing some signal processing. Looking for that click isn't going to be easy with all the environmental noise going on around the meter, but it'll be easier to tinker with software detection than trying to design a hardware detection circuit that works well.